# Link between Graph of function & Graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, graphing-functions

*Definition for graph of function:* For a function $ f:A \rightarrow B $ , $ \{ (x,f(x)) : x \in A \} $ is the graph of the function $ f $.

Graph [ with no loops, not directed, not weighted ] is a mathematical object of the format $ G = <V,E> $ , where $ V  $ is set of vertices, and $ E $ is a set of edges between vertices and is defined as $ E = \{ 
\{u,v\} : u,v \in V \} $

**Question**: What is the relation between 'Graph' as defined in graph theory and 'Graph of function' as defined above? It seems to me that the definition for graph of a function is some sort of set of edges ( and the vertices are $x \in A $? ), but I want to be sure.

Comment: In both instances, the term "graph" is used suggest "picture" or "diagram". Nothing more.

Comment: And if you look closely, the binary relations are very different. For a graph we have $E \subseteq V \times V$, for the graph of a function $f$ this is very different in general.

Comment: There are some instances, like this one, where the same term has two non-correlated meanings. Another instance: a  $\sigma$-field in measure theory for probability isn't at all a field. For a funny list, see [here](https://jeff560.tripod.com/ambiguities.html).

Comment: Hmm, I thought maybe if we define: $ V = \{ x : x \in A \} \cup  \{ f(x) : x \in A\}$  then we have $ E = \{ (x,f(x)) : x , f(x) \in V \} $ which is the set of edges and is termed as 'Graph of a function', and this is the apparent linkage. But this is if we regard the graph ( as in graph theory ) as directed.

Comment: @JeanMarie You have discouraged someone from posting the correct answer to this question, because it was already in a comment. As a result, there is only a very misleading answer to this question now! Comments aren't supposed to contain answers to begin with. If you wanted to discourage someone, you should have told the commenter to make their comment an answer.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov I agree. I will add my "undelete" to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, "yes", the questioner is perfectly correct. In more detail:

A Directed Graph, in the sense of vertices and edges, provided we agree to allow loops is exactly the same as a subset of the cartesian product $V \times V$ where $V$ is the set of vertices. The same structure is also called a binary relation on $V$.

Some graphs in that sense are functions from $V$ to $V$. These are the special graphs where
for every $v \in V$ there is exactly one edge $(v,w)$ in the graph for some $w \in V$.

When the graph of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is drawn, the points in the drawing (on the curve of the function) are all coordinate points in the plane
$\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

A function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ can always be thought of as a set of ordered pairs
$$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mid y = f(x)\}.$$
From this viewpoint the "graph of a function" is just a special case of a "directed graph" as in graph theory where the vertices are all the elements of $\mathbb{R}$ and the edges are all the pairs $(x, f(x))$. So an edge of the graph is a point in the plane.

This story still works for functions which are multivalued,  partial, or are not from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, etc.

If you think about the adjacency matrix of a graph on a finite set of vertices, you have exactly the same underlying idea as plotting the graph of a function. The places you put a $1$ (for the existence of an edge) in the matrix are points being selected as part of the plot. In the case of the adjacency matrix it's a discrete space rather than the dense real plane, but the graph in each case is determined by picking out points in a space with two axes along which the set of vertices is laid out.